# How to compile and run java programmes in Android terminal

Tags: java, android

I am using Terminal IDE on Android to compile and run `.java` files but I am not able to do that,

Actually i know how to change current path in windows (`cd desktop`) if it is on desktop but what about terminal IDE if it is on root of sd card.

It support Java because when i tried by typing `javac` it shows me Java version and app description says it can compile Java files,

So please help me out.

[Play Store Link For Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en)

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is the manual or tutorial for this development tool.

Comment: Not really! But acually i just want to know how to change current directory, i mean qhat should i type with cd(change directory) command (path of sd card), so i can locate my java file. Its giving me error as file not found.

Comment: Try this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGwogzTcDuc

Comment: Sorry brother but it didn't helped! I am still stuck with my question that how to change directory to SD card?( I am using nexus 7).       Anyways thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check this (slightly out of date) documentation for Terminal IDE -- [documentation](https://terminal-ide.googlecode.com/files/Terminal_IDE_Help.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

type

```
    
$HOME
```

which would take you to the root folder. Then

```
    
cd sdcard
```

this would take you to the

```
    
/sdcard/
```

folder, type

```
    
ls
//or
pwd
```

to check where you are.
also see the tutorials in help section, they'll show you how to use javac command properly,
or chek

```
    
cd $HOME
cd system/src/helloworld
```

type tab key after typing hel which will complete the path.
keep using

```
    
ls
```

just after changing to any folder to check the content of it.
hope this helps